# Unicorn + Rails Refused Connection on Nginx Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

My application is returning 502 error:

In the error.log:

2017/10/12 15:42:28 [error] 12727#12727: *415 connect() to unix:/var/www/autonomos/production/current/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.81.4, server: api.autonomosapp.com.br, request: "GET /v1/auth/validate_token HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/autonomos/production/current/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock:/v1/auth/validate_token", host: "api.autonomosapp.com.br"

My nginx/sites-enabled

```
upstream unicorn_autonomos_production {
  server unix:/var/www/autonomos/production/current/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  #listen 443 ssl;
  server_name api.autonomosapp.com.br;
  root /var/www/autonomos/production/current/public;

  access_log /var/www/autonomos/production/shared/log/access.log;
  error_log /var/www/autonomos/production/shared/log/error.log;

  client_max_body_size 500M;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  gzip_types application/x-javascript text/css;


  location /elb-status {
    return 200;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
     allow all;
     root /var/www/autonomos/production/current/public;
  }


  location ~* ^/assets/ { 
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry 
    # http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html 
    expires 1y; 
    add_header Cache-Control public; 

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a 
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't 
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header. 
    add_header Last-Modified ""; 
    add_header ETag ""; 
    break; 
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn_autonomos_production;
      break;
    }
  } 

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root /var/www/autonomos/production/current/public;
  }
}
```

nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My etc/init/unicorn_autonomos_production

```
start on runlevel [2]
stop on runlevel [016]

console owner

setuid autonomos
pre-start exec /usr/local/rvm/bin/autonomos_production_unicorn_rails -E production -c /var/www/autonomos/production/current/config/unicorn.rb -D > /tmp/upstart_autonomos_production.log 2>&1
post-stop exec kill `cat /var/www/autonomos/production/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`

respawn
```

unicorn.stderr.log

```
I, [2017-10-10T04:24:00.952787 #2245]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 2248 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2017-10-10T04:24:00.952946 #2245]  INFO -- : master complete
```

My unicorn_autonomos_production not in init.d, it is a problem?

When I try:

```
service unicorn_autonomos_production start
```

The error is:

**Failed to start unicorn_autonomos_production.service: Unit unicorn_autonomos_production.service not found.**

I reload the nginx server today, I needed to initialize the unicorn too? How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exec the command on terminal:

```
exec /usr/local/rvm/bin/autonomos_production_unicorn_rails -E production -c /var/www/autonomos/production/current/config/unicorn.rb -D > /tmp/upstart_autonomos_production.log 2>&1
```

and init unicorn